# New SXA multisite redirects to 404 but able to preview

Tags: sxa, multisite

This is an existing multisite SXA project under a single tenant, with following URLs:

https://dev.example.com      [International; Virtual Folder: /]
https://dev.example.com/cn   [China;         Virtual Folder: /cn]
https://dev.example.com/vi   [Vietnam;       Virtual Folder: /vi]

In the DEV environment (not local), I have duplicated an existing site and updated all the required settings, paths, references etc.  The Virtual folder for the new site is `/sg`.

I'm able to preview the new Singapore site with the related content. It also loads fine in the Experience editor mode.
The content is also published to `web` when I switch the database and verify.

But, when I browse https://dev.example.com/sg, it is redirecting to 404 page.
I guess, it is trying to look for `sg` item under the international Home node.

In the SXA manager, the new Singapore site's entries are correct for CM & CD.

How should I troubleshoot this.

Comment: I don't think it is looking for the item on your international site. As your other sites are working like /cn and /vi. Did you create item of cn and vi in your international site?

Comment: @SumitBhatia No I haven't. I'm guessing this could be any configuration/settings issue but I don't where to look at.

Comment: can you check this one? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/manage-multiple-sites-with-the-sxa-site-manager.html#:~:text=To%20manage%20multiple%20sites%20with,the%20ribbon%2C%20click%20Move%20Up.

Comment: @SumitBhatia Just to test I created "sg" item under international home, now. When I browse `https:dev.example.com/ph`, it loads the test page. So, I'm guessing this could be any configuration/settings issue but I don't where to look at.

Comment: you created item called "sg" but you are browsing /ph? Did you check with sg?

Comment: Can you also add the screenshot of your SXA site manager?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with how the site's for listed in SXA Site manager.

Arranging them in this order fixed the issue for me. The International site had to be at the end.

```
| Site Name       | Host Name                | Virtual Folder |    
|-----------------|--------------------------| ---------------|    
| Vietnam CD      | dev.example.com          | /vi            |
| Vietnam CM      | dev-authoring.example.com| /vi            |
| China CD        | dev.example.com          | /cn            |
| China CM        | dev-authoring.example.com| /cn            |
| Singapore CD    | dev.example.com          | /sg            |
| Singapore CM    | dev-authoring.example.com| /sg            |
| International CD| dev.example.com          | /              |
| International CM| dev-authoring.example.com| /              |
```

Comment: Yes, whenever you create a new site in SXA, you should check if it is not hidden by other sites using SXA site manager.